# SELENIUM/JAVA/MAVEN/JENKINS/FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am running a maven project (selenium/java), i created a data.properties file in my project for ease of driver change when running my tests. the data.properties path is referenced in my project like this : /Users/ugo.kaine/git/repository/wealthng/src/main/java/dependency/data.properties

it runs fine on my local machine but when i move the codes to jenkins from bitbucket and run from jenkins i get the following errors: [[1;31mERROR[m] wealthng.liquidateInvestment.validateLiquidateInvestment  Time elapsed: 0.037 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/ugo.kaine/git/repository/wealthng/src/main/java/dependency/data.properties (No such file or directory)
at wealthng.liquidateInvestment.validateLiquidateInvestment(liquidateInvestment.java:20)

I need solution on how to reference my data.property file in my code to avoid this error.

Comment: It puzzles me that a property file is located in `src/main/java/... `?

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you investigate using relative paths instead of absolute paths.
A starting point could be "`./src/main/java/dependency/data.properties`".

Maven proposes the common separation of code from additional data (like configuration), so that your properties would reside beneath `src/main/resources`.